# How does one have a Singleton Observe Changes to Core Data Model?

Tags: ios

How does one Observe changes to CoreData using a Singleton Object?

In my app every time the user adds a new CoreData FoodEntry I want to notify my Singleton which will sum up the calorie totals for the day and then my ViewController will be notified that the calorie totals for the day have changed and it can update the UI. So the Singleton is observing the CoreData context and the viewController is observing the Singleton number cruncher class.

My plan so far is implement the singleton and have it subscribe to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` then crunch the numbers in the callback method `handleDataModelChange`...I'm getting two errors

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

`+[FitWrench handleDataModelChange:]:` unrecognized selector sent to class 0x27a58

I set a exception breakpoint which occurs when I save the managedObjectContext but I haven't been able to get it to print out the userInfo...=(

```
@implementation Singleton

+ (Singleton *) sharedInstance
{
    static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];

        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *myManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(handleDataModelChange:) 
                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:myManagedObjectContext];

    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)handleDataModelChange:(NSNotification *)note;
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *deletedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey];
    NSSet *insertedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSInsertedObjectsKey];

    // Do something in response to this
    NSLog(@"%@ Objects Updated, %@ Objects Deleted, %@ Objects Inserted",[updatedObjects count],[deletedObjects count],[insertedObjects count]);
}

@end
```

Comment: I recommend against such practice. I never needed a singleton to observe CoreData context changes. Looking at your example I see that you plan on using single managed object context for everything which makes it more troublesome for you to create objects that might be inconsistent/invalid. Subscribe to context changes in the view controller that is responsible for managing core data managed objects.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a rogue semi-colon at the end of this line...?

```
- (void)handleDataModelChange:(NSNotification *)note;
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprised you're not getting a compile error here.NSLog(@"%@ Objects Updated, %@ Objects

```
Deleted, %@ Objects Inserted",[updatedObjects count],[deletedObjects count],[insertedObjects count]);
```

First placeholder is for an object, but [deletedObjects count] returns an NSUInteger.  %i would probably work better.

Comment: You're right, thank you...syntax isn't the issue though...this is a messy question at the moment...